# Taking away a User's Read/Write/Execute Permission

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, security

So I have a user that is able to go in `/etc` and read files like `httpd.conf`.

I would like to deny that user access to any critical locations such as `/etc`, `/var` and so on.

What would be the best way to do so? I don't really want to modify my whole folder/file permission just for one user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to set up a [chroot jail](http://www.serverschool.com/dedicated-servers/what-is-a-chroot-jail/) look at [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/).

The jail **ch** anges the **root**, as in `/`, to new path.

---

As a simple example as a start.

First off you would most likely want to have chroot directory on a separate
partition - such that the user can't fill your system partition.

But for sake of simplicity:

1. Make chroot directory:

   ```
   # mkdir /usr/chroot_test
   # cd /usr/chroot_test
   ```
2. Make system directories:

   ```
   # mkdir bin etc home lib var
   ```
3. Add some basic tools:

Here one can use `ldd` to find dependencies.

```
# ldd /bin/bash
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb774d000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0xb770a000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb7705000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb755a000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb774e000)
```

Copy them to chroot's lib:

```
# cp /lib/{libtinfo.so.5,libdl.so.2,libc.so.6,ld-linux.so.2} lib/
```

Now enter chroot

```
# chroot /usr/chroot_test
bash-4.2# ls
bash: ls: command not found
bash-4.2# pwd
/
bash-4.2# exit
exit
```

OK. Works. Add some more tools:

```
# sed '/=>/!d;/=>\s*(/d;s/.*=>\s*\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' < <(ldd /bin/{ls,cat,vi}) | sort -u)

... copy
```

Etc.

Then add chroot login (http://kegel.com/crosstool/current/doc/chroot-login-howto.html).

---

But, as mentioned, by using jailkit this can be simplified: http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html.

Answer (score 4):

You can use File access control Lists to remove permissions from specific users.  The command is setfacl, which Sets (Creates) an ACL on a File.

Example usage:

```
root@host:/tmp# date > f1
root@host:/tmp# ls -l f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root           30 Mar 28 12:12 f1
root@host:/tmp# setfacl -m u:johan:0 f1
root@host:/tmp# ls -l f1
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root          30 Mar 28 12:12 f1
```

Notice the + symbol after the permissions.  It tells you the file have an ACL set.  The setfacl command option -m tells it to create/modify an ACL.  The argument "u:johan:0" causes the User Entry for user "johan" to be set to "0", which is an abbreviation for permissions mode "0 0 0", equivalent to "--- --- ---" for the traditional "rwx rwx rwx" permission sets.

```
root@host:/tmp# getfacl f1
# file: f1
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:johan:---
group::r--
mask::r--
other::r--

root@host:/tmp# cat f1
Thu Mar 28 12:12:07 SAST 2013
root@host:/tmp# exit
```

After Exit the commands have the permissions of the specified user, eg "johan"

```
johan@host:/tmp> cat f1
cat: f1: Permission denied
```

Now having said all of that **be very careful**. Indiscriminately removing access from /etc WILL cause all kinds of failures and users will likely not be able to log in.  Many system functions read, with the permissions of the logged in user, various configuration files in /etc.  However preventing users access from specific individual files is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The files you are so worried about are *meant* to be publicly accessible. The really sensitive data is locked away. Yes, Unix is (by design and history) a rather open system.

If you are so worried about that user, just lock her out. A user that you don't trust has no place on your machines.

Or go check with your paranoidist, perhaps it is getting out of control.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the very helpful comments. I just wanted my allowed SSH login to not be able to read important files like Apache configs, if some how it DOES get hacked into. However, you're right, let's not worry about that because extra security is not important at all.